# how to search and find all available telecom network in android devices in the area

Tags: android, telecommunication

I want to search all the available telecom network available in the area.

means I want to use the available gsm/LTE or any other antenna on the device to search all the available network.

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has changed recently this is not possible - the logic is that you don't want an app being able to search for and overwrite a users preferred network, although this is not really a reason not to at least let the user know what is available.

You can direct a user to the network preferences page which may be the best compromise at this time.